# Hidden skills to survive thirst and hunger while on The Dusty Path? Acquired through dying?

Tags: a-dark-room

I keep seeing *vague mentions* ("Slow Metabolism", "Desert Rat") that there are skills that help the player to survive in the wilderness / dusty road in such a way that you die of dehydration/starvation less.

So far I'm not sure if there is such a way. They seem to be called "Slow Metabolism" and "Desert Rat". Anyone have any clue what does it take for them to be acquired?

**edit** I'm not talking about stocking up with cured meat or getting a lot of water. They all run out, eventually.

**edit** to clarify, "vague mentions" seem to point to the code itself mentioning some skills like that. something about dying of thirst or of hunger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to the **thirst** thing is:

- Stock up on cured meat (10) (so you have enough time to die of thirst, *not* hunger)
- While on **A Dusty Path**, keep walking until you die of dehydration (thirst). Repeat 10 times.

When you die and unlock the **Desert Rat**, you get a notification saying:
**"learned to love the dry air."**

---

The answer to the **hunger** thing is:

- Stock up on 1 cured meat and plenty (10-20) of water (so you have enough time to die of hunger, *not* thirst)
- Go for walksies. Walk until "The meat has run out." Walk until "starvation sets in". Walk until "the world fades." Repeat 10 times.

When you die and unlock the **Slow Metabolism**, you get a notification saying:
**"learned how to ignore the hunger."**